# JQuery wait untill class is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i am trying to achieve is create image selector in my `js`.

I have managed to do everything expect to get back url image.

Here is current flow of my work.

I create empty div inside my html like this:

```
<div id="UploadBox" hidden></div>
```

Then I add script like this:

```
$("#ChangeTumbnailBtn").click(function () {
    var up = new Upload(UploadBox);
    $("#UploadBox").show(); 
    //My idea is to wait here until Upload class says something and then proceed with code and get up.Response
});
```

and my `Upload` class is like this:

```
class Upload {
    constructor(ContainerID) {
        var maincontainer = ContainerID;
        var SelectedImageUrl;

        $(maincontainer).css("position", "absolute");
        $(maincontainer).css("top", $(window).height() / 100 * 2);
        $(maincontainer).css("left", $(window).width() / 100)
        $(maincontainer).css("height", $(window).height() / 100 * 96);
        $(maincontainer).css("width", $(window).width() / 100 * 98);
        $(maincontainer).css("padding", "15px");

        $(maincontainer).css("-webkit-box-sizing", "border-box");
        $(maincontainer).css("-moz-box-sizing", "border-box");
        $(maincontainer).css("box-sizing", "border-box");
        $(maincontainer).css("border", "solid 1px");
        $(maincontainer).css("background-color", "#e0e0e0");
        $(maincontainer).css("border-radius", "10px");

        $(maincontainer).append("<button id='UploadButtonClose' style='position: absolute; right: 15px; border: none; background-color: transparent'>X</button>");
        $(maincontainer).append("</div>");
        $(maincontainer).append("<h2 style='margin: 0'>Galery</h2>");

        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Gallery/GetAll",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                        $(maincontainer).append("<img class='selectingImage' style='float: left; margin: 10px; max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px;' src='/Uploads/Images/" + data[i] + "' />");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
            $("#UploadButtonClose").click(function () {
                $(maincontainer).html("");
                $(maincontainer).fadeOut();
                delete this;
            });
            $(".selectingImage").click(function () {
                SelectedImageUrl = this.attr("src");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

So how could i wait for class to "close" or somehow say me "hey, continue with your code now" in place where i commented `//My idea...`

Comment: Just use a callback

Comment: Or trigger an event

Comment: @Wendelin oh. I have just researched that and it worked. Thank you.